# How do I access an internal ELB from a peered VPC?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, routing, internal-dns, amazon-vpc

I have two AWS VPCs in the same region. **VPC A** has an internal ELB that routes to my application. **VPC B** has resources that need access to this application. The VPCs are peered, with routing tables having routes that point to each others' main CIDR block.

Currently, I can access the ELB from instances in the same **VPC A**, but not yet from those in **VPC B**.

How do I set up DNS and routing so that the resources in **VPC B** can resolve and access this ELB?

Comment: You could try [Route53 Resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use the DNS name of the internal load balancer.

> The nodes of an internal load balancer have only private IP addresses. The DNS name of an internal load balancer is publicly resolvable to the private IP addresses of the nodes. Therefore, internal load balancers can only route requests from clients with access to the VPC for the load balancer.

You could also create a CNAME record in Route53 (or other DNS service) if you'd like to name it something different.

If the routes are correct for your VPC peer, your application (VPC B) will be able to resolve and reach the application in VPC A.

Make sure you add entries in the Internal Load Balancers Security Group(s) to allow traffic from VPC B

**References**

[Internal Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html)
[VPC Peering Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html)

Comment: The application in VPC B is currently able to resolve but somehow can't connect to the ELB. I feel like I have done all of these things, but I will go back to verify each one. Thanks!

Comment: It turned out one of the route tables I edited to allow traffic between the two VPCs was not attached to the correct subnet - a rookie mistake I guess. Thanks for the help!